# How to translate language in Symfony 2.1, according to accept language header?

Tags: symfony-2.1

How we can make automatically go to german, if browser Accept language is de_DE or de(German), else go to english(all other browser Accept languages)?

my listener

```
namespace xxxx
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class LocaleListener
{
    private $container;
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, $defaultLocale)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$this->container->has('request')) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $this->container->get('request');
        $request->setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage($this->defaultLocale));
    }
}
```

service.yml

```
  my_locale_listener:
    class: Wishbot\WebBundle\Listener\LocaleListener
    tags: [{ name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 100 }]
    arguments: [ @service_container, ['de','en' ] ]
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you go through the translation chapter in Symfony 2 documentation.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html

It will explain you as to how to maintain your site in different languages.